# git: list all repos on a remote server?

Tags: git

My git client is set up. Have ssh set up, ssh public is on the git server.

I know there are some repos in that server... how do I list them?

For reference:

```
server: 192.168.1.230
using SSH
my user name: sam@demosam.com
```

(I am having trouble really understanding the syntax of git remote add. For example, this command:

```
git remote add pb git://github.com/paulboone/ticgit.git
```

I do not understand where the path name, or the .git file come from. also ssh seems to missing.

Another example:

```
git clone ssh://user@master:path/my_rep
```

I don't understand the params after // .... what are they?
)

Comment: What Git software is the server running? It depends on that. You can try doing an `ssh git@hostname.of.your.server` and see what it  tells you. Your other questions are probably better suited as separate posts—I'd take them out here and ask a new question about the `git remote` software.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183724/list-of-remotes-for-a-git-repository